# Clickable UI Bootstrap tooltip

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create a clickable tooltip on an event in the calendar using Angular UI Calendar(http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/).

The tooltip is rendered:

```
$scope.eventRender = function( event, element, view ) { 
  $timeout(function(){
    $(element).attr('tooltip', event.title);
    $compile(element)($scope);
  });
};
```

Already customized with tooltip-placement, tooltip-class and it's good.
But I want to make the tooltip don't hide when I'm hovering the same tooltip(like this: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/jLkcs/5/).
Does anyone know how to make this? Thank you.
-Sorry the bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootstrap tooltips are based on hover and are intended only for displaying info, not for interaction. you may try using a popover instead

Comment: I agree. It's better to use the right tool for the job instead forcing another tool to behave in a way it's not intended to.